# Blend in/blend into?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, syntactic-analysis, phrase-usage

could someone please suggest me if the sentence below is correct or not (in context to the usage of blend in/blend into)? Please also share the reason/logic behind your answer. Thanks.

> "Never imagined how beautifully one can blend comedy in a scary movie without compromising its thriller quotient."

Also, thriller quotient or thrill quotient - which one do you think is correct in the above context?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Blend into is more graceful, and it fits better with "without compromising"  as one might say "stir warm cream into coffee without diluting its heat." The idea is that it's primarily a scary movie with some comedic elements.

"Thriller quotient" is the intended meaning. Both comedy and thriller are types of books, plays, or films. Other types include romance and documentary.

Additionally, what you have written is a sentence fragment, since the subject (I) is not stated. Sentence fragments are common in conversation.

Comment: When you blend cream into coffee, thes elements are no longer distinguishable. I don't think the author meant that here. If he did, you would not be able to tell which is the comedy part and which is the thriller part. That's why it's badly expressed.

Answer (score 0):

**Blend something into** means the thing being blended loses its original form.
This is apparent in cooking recipes:

> Blend the milk into the flour mixtures  until smooth.

whereas: Here: "Never imagined how beautifully one can blend comedy in a scary movie without compromising its thriller quotient."

The author does not mean blend in or into so it loses its form. Because if he did (like a cooking ingredient), it would no longer be comedy, would it?

> So, he has not written it very clearly.

The author means: blend comedy with the thriller bits, where there would be no dilution. **This is like fabric or material, where one sees: this is a cotton blend. That is, a mix of cotton and some other thread.**

**This movie is a blend of a comedy and a thriller.**

Please note: this does not cover the idea of blend as the opposite of standing out. For example: You can always see him in a crowd. That hat does not blend in with what other people are wearing.

Comment: A quotient is a portion or a fraction. The use of the word quotient implies that the film is primarily a thriller with some comedic elements.  As another example, "This stew has a small meat quotient." Meat is an integral part of the stew, not discrete elements added later.

Comment: The word quotient doesn't change anything. Yes, the stew has a strong meat quotient, sure.  You don't blend in the meat do you?? I covered that usage. Very clearly. That is why **blend in** does not work. Substitute quotients for the word bits in my first sentence. The movie is part comedy, part thriller.

Comment: I don't think you are answering the original question about blend in / blend into. You are instead recasting the sentence to fit your idea that the film is not a thriller when it has comedic elements.

Comment: And I think you are doing the same. The comedy and thriller quotients of a movie would not be said to blend in because then you would have neither.  Blended things do not stand out on their own. They become "a soup of the two".